# PHP Sending content of textarea through email using 'a href' tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

For HTML code,

```
<textarea name="email_content" rows="6" placeholder="Write something"></textarea>
<a href="./something.php">Send it</a>
```

For PHP code,

```
<?php
    $email="abcde@abc.com";
    $head = "From: email\r\n";
    $head .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $title= "Title Test";
    $body = "The text in the textarea";  
    $success = mail($email, $title, $body, $head);
?>
```

I want the text in the textarea to go to $body in PHP code.

Also, I want to send email in utf-8.

Please help!

Comment: I recommend making this a `form` and styling the `submit` button to look like a link, instead of trying to use an actual link to submit form data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because you're not [*`POST`ing*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) the data (you could do it if the email you send was always the same). Like @David said, though, you can make the submit button *look* like a hyperlink.

Here's the HTML markup:

```
<form method="POST" action="./something.php">
    <textarea name="email_content" rows="6" placeholder="Write something"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="hyperlink" value="Send it">
</form>
```

Here's the CSS styling:

```
.hyperlink {
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: underline;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

This is how it would look: http://jsfiddle.net/VKuEF/1/.

And in the `something.php` PHP script, to grab the value of the the textarea you'd do

```
$body = $_POST['email_content'];
```

And then use it to send the email. To use UTF-8 encoding for your email, you could add the `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header to your message body.